# Localizing SQL Server Reporting Services reports?

Tags: reporting-services, localization, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008

How would one go about localizing SSRS reports?

Let´s say I have a report that contains a label with the text "Total Sales" (in Norwegian language, which is where I come from) and I want to use the same report for our danish and swedish customers, so the actual text needs to change slightly.

Do I need to make copies of all the reports and localize them manually, or is there any way to do this in a more automated way?

Could I for instance use expressions for those texts instead, and add our own localizing system to the reports, ie. use the following expression:

```
=Translate("Total Sales")
```

which would call one of our .NET methods which would do the translation?

We´re in the beginning of using SSRS reports, so if there is a difference between 2005 and 2008 in this regard, please say which version you´re referring to, as we haven´t decided which one(s) to support yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your expressions requires you to register first the custom assembly for the report server.

This has not changed from 2005 to 2008.

A guide how this can be done is located over [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/balajiintel/CustomAssemblyinRS06302005081435AM/CustomAssemblyinRS.aspx)

So, after completing all the steps you will be able to translate the stuff you need.

Comment: What if we want to use local reports, it should be easier then I suppose? Ie. only use the report designer and the report viewer controls in .NET?

Comment: never had the need to use the local viewer :)