# Localization in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, localization, ssrs-2008-r2

can some one tell me/help me about localization of SSRS repors? 
How can I change language of labels (I have more than 50 reports and more than 200 different labels)?

I found one way 
http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2011/09/localization-of-your-ssrs-reports.html

but is there some other and faster way to change language of report labels?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localizing SQL Server Reporting Services reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721889/localizing-sql-server-reporting-services-reports)

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to implement a robust system for managing multiple localisations for a set of reports then something similar to the linked example in your question would be ideal.

However if you just want to replace text strings in the report definitions for a single localisation, e.g. replace all instances of "Revenue" with "Opbrengst", then you could do a find and replace in the text of the .rdl files. You can do this for a set of files in something like Notepad++. This has some obvious risks as you could unintentionally replace values in expressions etc. that could break the report, so would need to be done very carefully and be followed up with comprehensive testing.